# Nodejs Skaffold local development to prod process

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, skaffold

New to container and kubernetes.

I'm trying to set thing up so we have the parity of the local development all the way through prod.

Skaffold seems to be a good way to do this but I'm confused by a few small pieces of the examples and 'ideal workflow'

Referencing https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/tree/master/examples/nodejs

The dockerfile they give uses nodemon. Wouldn't this same container be used in prod? Wouldn't it be bad to be running nodemon in prod?

How do I set up a kubernetes local development environment with live file sync and use the same resources (in order to have idempotency) for production?

Comment: You should probably open this as an issue on that repo. :) Looks like the example isn't clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely right. Using nodemon in a production container is not recommended. Instead, you generally want different images or different entrypoints for dev vs staging vs production. There are two options to solve this:

**1. Multiple Dockerfiles**
You can configure profiles in Skaffold and tell Skaffold to use a different Dockerfile during the build step: https://skaffold.dev/docs/how-tos/profiles/

**2. Single Dockerfile + Dev Overrides**
If you do not want to manage multiple Dockerfiles, you could use a dev tool that supports dev overrides. DevSpace (https://github.com/devspace-cloud/devspace) for example differentiates between `devspace deploy` and `devspace dev` which applies certain overrides, e.g. overriding the entrypoint of the image. In this case you could specify 2 npm scrips in your package.json and start dev mode with the entrypoint `npm start dev` and the production mode using `npm start`.